# Why is matplotlib installed with ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, numpy, matplotlib

Today I upgraded to ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 as well as the 64-bit background processing tool and noticed that both **[numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)** and [**matplotlib**](http://matplotlib.org/) were installed with Python.  In fact, in the "**[What's New?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//016w0000005v000000)**" section for 10.2.1, it states:

> ArcGIS 10.2.1 has been upgraded to include Python 2.7.5. Third-party
>   Python libraries have also been upgraded: NumPy has been upgraded to
>   1.7.1 and matplotlib to 1.3.0.

I understand that there are a number of tools in ArcGIS which use numpy such as:

- **[NumpyArrayToRaster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000007q000000)**
- **[RasterToNumpyArray](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000)**

as well as a number of tools in the **[Data Access Module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_the_data_access_module/018w00000008000000/)**.

*Do any of the tools in ArcGIS directly utilise the matplotlib module, and if so, which ones? Or is it installed just in case people want to make better looking charts and graphs, etc. than are possible in ArcMap?*

Comment: +1 http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/arcgis-101-and-matplotlib.html suggests it may be the latter

Comment: @PolyGeo No. We only bundle third-party libraries if they provide some value/functionality to core GP tools. It's a lot of paperwork to include a Python library, we need a lot of justification to do so.

Comment: @JasonScheirer That makes sense - your input is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, some of the tools use matplotlib.

For example (in my 10.1 install):

- Multi-Distance Spatial Cluster Analysis (Ripleys K Function)

  `<ArcGIS install folder>\ArcToolbox\Scripts\KFunction.py`
- Incremental Spatial Autocorrelation (Moran's I)

  `<ArcGIS install folder>\ArcToolbox\Scripts\MoransI_Increment.py`
- Ordinary Least Squares

  `<ArcGIS install folder>ArcToolbox\Scripts\OLS.py`
- Group Similar Features

  `<ArcGIS install folder>ArcToolbox\Scripts\Partition.py`
- matplotlib is also used in `<ArcGIS install folder>ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSReport.py` which is a module that contains "*Reporting Functions for ESRI Script Tools as well as users for their own scripts.*"

Paraphrasing Jason Scheirer's comment - third-party Python libraries (such as matplotlib) may be included with reservations, and only if they are essential (ie core tools depend on them). ESRI don't want to bloat the installation footprint or freeze users on a particular version of a Python library unless they absolutely have to.

Comment: Yes. We include third-party Python libraries with reservations, and only if they are essential (ie core tools depend on them). We don't want to bloat the installation footprint or freeze users on a particular version of a Python library unless we absolutely have to.

Comment: It just backs up your answer, though. You're free to edit your answer with those details. You even did the due diligence I would not have with explaining which tools used it.